# React Scroll position rendering not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

You want to make an event occur when scrolling to that location.
In the current mode, it only works when reloaded at the location, and does not work when it comes to the location while scrolling down from above.
I think I need to use `useState`, but I tried in many ways but failed. Please help me.

```
useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init();
    var cnt = document.querySelectorAll(".count")[props.num];
    var water = document.querySelectorAll(".water")[props.num];
    const Skills = document.querySelector('#skills');
    const percentscroll = window.scrollY + Skills.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    if (window.scrollY >= percentscroll) {
        var percent = cnt.innerText;
        var interval;
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            percent++;
            cnt.innerHTML = percent;
            water.style.transform = 'translate(0' + ',' + (100 - percent) + '%)';
            if (percent == props.percent) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 60);
    }
    
}, [])
```

Comment: why don't you want to use useLayout?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it the React way. In React, you use refs to keep tract of DOM nodes. For you case about scrolling to a certain location, you should use **IntersectionObserver** ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)). There are many libraries that can help you but I suggest doing it the vanilla way to learn more. Here is an example from [dev.to](https://dev.to/producthackers/intersection-observer-using-react-49ko)

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const callbackFunction = (entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
  };

  const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, options);
    if (containerRef.current) observer.observe(containerRef.current);

    return () => {
      if (containerRef.current) observer.unobserve(containerRef.current);
    };
  }, [containerRef, options]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{isVisible}</div>
      <div>A lot of content ...</div>
      <div ref={containerRef}>Observe me</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```